# How can I run a Metro-style/WinRT app as a different user?

Tags: windows-10

The "Run as different user" option doesn't exist for WinRT/Metro-style apps - how can I run these apps as a different user within my domain?

Trying to start the link from a simple "runas" doesn't work..

Answer (score 2):

This was slightly simpler than expected - simply needed to change user context **before** trying to launch the link.

So, the answer:

**Step 1)** Locate the *.lnk file that launches the WinRT app in question (you can create one if it doesn't exist, IIRC)

**Step 2)** Launch CMD.EXE as the target user using "runas /user:DOMAIN\USER2 cmd.exe"

**Step 3)** Cd to the directory containing the .lnk file, then simply type it into the command line & hit enter.